# Ability for the user to sort by multiple NSTableView columns

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nssortdescriptor

By setting an array of `NSSortDescriptor`s I can sort a `NSTableView` by multiple columns. Is there a (ideally builtin) way to allow the user to achieve the same result.

I remember that (I guess on Windows) in some cases I used to be able to `Shift` + click multiple columns to achieve this result.

The result might look something like this:

[image: multi-sort]